# What is the significance of a "pink pill"?

Tags: practice-of-medicine, pill

I've looked at Wikipedia and Wiktionary. I've wondered about this for a long time.

Initially, I though that it was a color code/metaphor for estrogen (female hormones), but then I heard "little pink pills" mentioned in an old song from the 1960s, as well as in an obscure context from the 1980s. None of them explained what they are based on the context.

So what are they? What is a "pink pill", and where was it invented? What does a pill of pink color signify?

I don't think I've ever actually seen a pink pill. They are always either white, "natural" (whatever natural ingredients were put in them), brown or dark-blue or something. It seems to be rather arbitrary.

I wish I could understand what they keep referring to with "pink pills".

Comment: I think this question is a bit out of place here. Not to sound rude, but I think you are seeking the meaning of an urban phrase or a slang. Here, you must have a valid question pertaining to medical science (please read the guidelines) and must have had some prior research. Furthermore, your question is widely digressive and asks multiple questions within itself. Again, please read the guidelines.

Comment: Either way, the closest meaning I could find for pink pills is this: "Pill all the major drug companies are trying to either develop/get approved to boost female libido. Pink because viagra is known as "the little blue pill". " (Urban Dictionary)

Comment: I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Williams%27_Pink_Pills_for_Pale_People which claimed to be a cure for [chorea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chorea)

Comment: You could ask this at MusicFans.SE, if you can provide the lyrics of those songs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about medical sciences as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 1):

Pink is a [common pill color](https://pillbox.nlm.nih.gov/results.html?medicine_name=&imprint=&shape=&color=Pink&inactive_ingredients=&repackaged=false&page=1&items_per_page=20). Nothing can be known about the composition of a pill based solely on its color; pink does not indicate any particular drug or class of drugs.

In recent years, a reference to the "little pink pill" in the media:

https://www.nbcnews.com/health/sexual-health/fda-approves-controversial-female-viagra-restrictions-n412116

https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation-now/2015/08/18/addyi-drug-sprout-pharmaceuticals-fda/31963219/

https://www.wnycstudios.org/podcasts/otm/segments/little-pink-pill

may refer to the drug flibanserin, used to treat impaired libido in women, but this would not explain references in the 1960s or 1980s.